# In Truffle, in which "level of abstraction" do the results of a partial evaluation belong?

Tags: truffle, graalvm

I'm trying to understand how partial evaluation works in the Truffle language framework. I'm reading the papers [Practical Partial Evaluation for High-Performance Dynamic Language Runtimes](https://chrisseaton.com/rubytruffle/pldi17-truffle/pldi17-truffle.pdf) and [One VM to Rule Them All](http://lafo.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/papers/2013_Onward_OneVMToRuleThemAll.pdf).

I gather that, for performing PE, Truffle depends on the Graal JIT, as implied by this diagram:

[image]

Also, quoting from the first paper:

> Graal compiles Java bytecode to optimized machine code, and can serve
>   as a replacement for the Java HotSpot server compiler. We extended it
>   with a frontend that performs PE, and added intrinsic methods that
>   support our core primitives.

My question is: do the *results* of a PE actually exist as JVM bytecode at any point? Or are they directly constructed using Graal's [*internal*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6688/214dab5456c75c99f8171846242e09d4f5e3.pdf) representation, and converted to native code straightaway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do the results of a PE actually exist as JVM bytecode at any point?

No

> Or are they directly constructed using Graal's internal representation, and converted to native code straightaway?

Yes

Comment: Thanks. So the partial evaluator works like a JIT, but one that, by limiting itself to AST nodes, and profiting from the Truffle instrumentation put into the interpreters, is able to optimize interpreter execution beyond what would be achievable by a regular JIT.

Comment: I think about it more that partial evaluation is the first phase of the JIT. Truffle keeps track of "hotness" of ASTs and when one gets hot it submits it for compilation and the first step in that compilation is to partially evaluate the AST.